# Hand Tracking: Tracking One Hand At A Time Instead Of Both

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mediapipe

I'm currently working on a hand tracking simulation, using MediaPipe and Unity3D. The problem is that while both hands are being tracked(By MediaPipe) only one is actively moving in Unity while the other stays still. You can still switch between left and right hands (depends on which is moving more), but both are unable to move together. It may be something to do with my `else If Statements`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HandTracking : MonoBehaviour
{

    public UDPReceive udpReceive;
    public GameObject[] handPoints;
    public GameObject[] handPointsB;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        string data = udpReceive.data;
        string handType = udpReceive.handType;
        data = data.Remove(0, 1);
        data = data.Remove(data.Length-1, 1);
        
        print(data);
        string[] points = data.Split(',');
        print(points[0]);

        for ( int i=0; i<21;  i++ ){
        float x1 = float.Parse(points[i*3])/80;
        float y1 = float.Parse(points[i*3 + 1])/80;
        float z1 = float.Parse(points[i*3 + 2])/80;


        float x2 = float.Parse(points[i*3])/80;
        float y2 = float.Parse(points[i*3 + 1])/80;
        float z2 = float.Parse(points[i*3 + 2])/80;

        
        if (handType == "Right" && handType == "Left"){
            handType = "Both";
        }


        Debug.Log("handType: " + handType);

        if (handType == "Right" || handType == "Both")
        {
            handPoints[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x1, y1, z1);
        }
        else if (handType == "Left" || handType == "Both")
        {
            handPointsB[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Unexpected handType: " + handType);
        }


        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: well `handType == "Right" && handType == "Right"` will always be true, but the same thing cant have 2 values, so it cant be Left which is arguably what you meant..

You need to have a left hand thing and a right hand thing and if both things then both, your if would then do if right hand  or both do right hand things. If left hand or both then do left hand things.

Comment: Sorry That was a typo on my end, but sadly it still doesn't change anything

Comment: well as i explained...